# Laravel: User notification fails to run when executed by the queue due to a InvalidArgumentException : Database [mysql] not configured error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to queue notifications in my laravel project. Whenever a notifications is queued it successfully makes a record in the jobs table with the specified delay. However, when the job is executed, it fails due to this error `InvalidArgumentException : Database [mysql] not configured`. I can schedule regular jobs in the queue which run properly but any notifications I attempt to queue fail. They do work when queueing in sync mode if that matters.

I've also cleared my cache and config `php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear`

I have database defined in `config/queue.php`:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),
'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
    ...
    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],
```

and I have mysql defined in `config/database.php`

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => '',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', DB_HOST),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', DB_NAME),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', DB_USER),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', DB_PASS),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        ...
```

I have `dd(config('database.connections'));` in my `AppServiceProdivder.php` which out puts the correct result:

```
array:4 [
  "mysql" => array:15 [
    "driver" => "mysql"
    "url" => null
    "host" => "127.0.0.1"
    "port" => "3306"
    "database" => "****"
    "username" => "****"
    "password" => "****"
    "unix_socket" => ""
    "charset" => "utf8mb4"
    "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
    "prefix" => ""
    "prefix_indexes" => true
    "strict" => false
    "engine" => "InnoDB"
    "options" => []
  ],
  ...
]
```

I have found that when the notification job is executed the database connections are removed and replaced with a `default` connection which matches my defined mysql connection. However, laravel is looking for a `mysql` config not `default` which causes the job to fail.

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=****
DB_USERNAME=****
DB_PASSWORD=****

CACHE_DRIVER=file
#SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER=database
```

Here is the stacktrace for the job error:

```
[2020-12-15 10:09:02] local.ERROR: Database connection [mysql] not configured. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Database connection [mysql] not configured. at /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:152)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(115): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->configuration()
#1 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(86): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->makeConnection()
#2 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1257): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->connection()
#3 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1223): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::resolveConnection()
#4 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1052): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->getConnection()
#5 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(969): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#6 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1005): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newModelQuery()
#7 /var/www/vhost1/master/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1031): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#8 /var/www/vhost1/master/vendor/illuminate/queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(114): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newQueryForRestoration()
```

EDIT:

Output from `\Log::info($this->app['config']['database.connections']);` inside `DatabaseManager.php` line `149`

```
[2020-12-16 09:19:26] local.INFO: array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'database' => '****',
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
  ),
)  
[2020-12-16 09:19:26] local.INFO: array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'database' => '****',
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
  ),
)
```

Comment: This is odd, and might require a bit of troubleshooting. It's trying to access the database, but can't, because it's not loading the right configuration. First, make sure you only have one database.php. Then go into the DatabaseManager.php, and add `\Log::info($this->app['config']['database.connections']);` above the line `$connections = $this->app['config']['database.connections'];` and try the queue again. It will fail, but add the configurations to your Laravel log. Make sure to remove the line when you're done. See what database configurations it's loading.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the output. It looks like my connections are reduced to a default connection but it looks like it should still work...

Comment: The `DatabaseManager` is looking for a config with the name `mysql` but as you can see only `default` exists causing the job to fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be resetting my database connections. Looking through the log some more it lookes like laravel keeps switching between the two configs which my default values and the default config which causes my notification to fail.

Comment: If I manually change the config used inside the `DatabseManager` to use my `mysql` values it works fine. Obviously not a solution but it does show that the root of the issue is with my database connection.

Comment: I would probably track down which config file that is (`grep -R "'driver'" config/* | grep mysql` from the project root, then check each file ) and see if you can modify that.

Comment: The only result I'm getting is `config/databse.php` where I define the mysql config. Good idea though! I hadn't check for that yet.

Comment: Can you show the `failed` section of your queue config?

Comment: I've added that dailed config to the queue file. driver = database and database = mysql

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I'm at a loss. I don't know where it's pulling the default configuration from , which has fewer elements than your mysql configuration (missing prefix_indexes, strict, engine, and options).

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. Another developer was resetting the database connections in a legacy section of our code base outside of the original laravel project. I'm not sure how its effecting the notification queue from where it's located but regardless it was the root of the issue. I doubt anyone else will run into this same scenario but if you do, I fixed it by re-adding my `mysql` connection with the config name specified.

````
$this->capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => '',
    'host' => DB_HOST,
    'port' => '3306',
    'database' => DB_NAME,
    'username' => DB_USER,
    'password' => DB_PASS,
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'options' => [],
], 'mysql');```
````